# Como crear back-end para pedir información a api externa? Error CORS desde React.js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, api, cors

estoy desarrollando una pagina web, en React.js, para ver una lista clasificatoria entre unas cuantas personas. Esta pide datos, las puntuaciones personales, a una api, en concreto: https://euw1.api.riotgames.com. El problema, es que para hacer uso de los datos de esta api, se necesita una api_key, por lo que cada vez que intento hacer una petición al servidor me salta este error:

- Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed
  by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Por lo que he estado leyendo, tengo que crear un back-end para hacer la petición des de allí. De manera que nadie pueda ver la api_key desde el front-end. El problema es que después de mucho leer, no sé ni por dónde empezar. Ni siquiera sé cómo hacer búsquedas en google para aprender a hacer esto. Me seria de mucha utilidad si alguien me da algún consejo o guía para poder crear este backend. En cualquier caso, esta es la petición que hago desde React.js:

```
                let url = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/'+jugadores[i]+'?api_key=xxxx';
                let response  = await fetch(url);
                let dt = await response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo ejemplo práctico de como consumir un API en React:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/videos/1", true);  
request.send();

request.onReadyStateChange = function() {  
    if (request.status == 200) { … }
}
```

Te dejo el link de un enlace de donde lo extraje:
https://medium.com/@jorge.basilio.94/como-consumir-un-api-en-react-js-ba4130386a61

https://pusher.com/tutorials/consume-restful-api-react